# Android Studio Debugger not showing step button

Tags: android, android-studio

As you can see the Android studio is not showing the debug options for this specific project. other then this project its working perfectly fine. if you need any thing specific please ask me

**Android Studio Version:**

Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1

Build #AI-213.7172.25.2113.9014738, built on September 1, 202

[image: Android Studio snapshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the "Show Options Menu" button as I've highlighted in the screenshot below, and check the "Show Toolbar" item.

[image]